# Continuous Fourier transform on discrete data using Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, fft

I have some periodic data, but the amount of data is not a multiple of 
the period. How can I Fourier analyze this data? Example:

% Let's create some data for testing:

```
data = Table[N[753+919*Sin[x/623-125]], {x,1,25000}]
```

% I now receive this data, but have no idea that it came from the 
 formula above. I'm trying to reconstruct the formula just from 'data'.

% Looking at the first few non-constant terms of the  Fourier series:

```
ListPlot[Table[Abs[Fourier[data]][[x]], {x,2,20}], PlotJoined->True, 
 PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

shows an expected spike at 6 (since the number of periods is really 
25000/(623*2*Pi) or about 6.38663, though we don't know this).

% Now, how do I get back 6.38663? One way is to "convolve" the data with 
 arbitrary multiples of Cos[x].

```
convolve[n_] := Sum[data[[x]]*Cos[n*x], {x,1,25000}]
```

% And graph the "convolution" near n=6:

```
Plot[convolve[n],{n,5,7}, PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

we see a spike roughly where expected.

% We try FindMaximum:

```
FindMaximum[convolve[n],{n,5,7}]
```

but the result is useless and inaccurate:

```
FindMaximum::fmmp:  
   Machine precision is insufficient to achieve the requested accuracy or 
    precision. 

Out[119]= {98.9285, {n -> 5.17881}}
```

because the function is very wiggly.

% By refining our interval (using visual analysis on the plots), we 
 finally find an interval where convolve[] doesn't wiggle too much:

```
Plot[convolve[n],{n,6.2831,6.2833}, PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and FindMaximum works:

```
FindMaximum[convolve[n],{n,6.2831,6.2833}] // FortranForm 
List(1.984759605826571e7,List(Rule(n,6.2831853071787975)))
```

% However, this process is ugly, requires human intervention, and 
 computing convolve[] is REALLY slow. Is there a better way to do this?

% Looking at the Fourier series of the data, can I somehow divine the 
 "true" number of periods is 6.38663? Of course, the actual result 
 would be 6.283185, since my data fits that better (because I'm only 
 sampling at a finite number of points).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Mathematica help for the Fourier function / Applications / Frequency Identification:
Checked on version 7

```
n = 25000;
data = Table[N[753 + 919*Sin[x/623 - 125]], {x, 1, n}];
pdata = data - Total[data]/Length[data];
f = Abs[Fourier[pdata]];
pos = Ordering[-f, 1][[1]]; (*the position of the first Maximal value*)  
fr = Abs[Fourier[pdata Exp[2 Pi I (pos - 2) N[Range[0, n - 1]]/n], 
   FourierParameters -> {0, 2/n}]];
frpos = Ordering[-fr, 1][[1]];

N[(pos - 2 + 2 (frpos - 1)/n)]
```

returns 6.37072

Comment: Fantastic! I followed the steps through 'pos' (normalize the data and find the largest Fourier coefficient [constant term being 0 due to normalization]), but what magic is the fr= line doing? That seems to be the crux of what I was looking for.

Comment: It is doing a fourier again, on pdata*e^i(...), and uses properties of the Fourier transform to calculate the correction / do the magic.

Answer (score 3):

Look for the period length using autocorrelation to get an estimate:

```
autocorrelate[data_, d_] := 
 Plus @@ (Drop[data, d]*Drop[data, -d])/(Length[data] - d)

ListPlot[Table[{d, autocorrelate[data, d]}, {d, 0, 5000, 100}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A smart search for the first maximum away from d=0 may be the best estimate you can get form the available data?

Comment: I realize that this does not solve the question posed in the title, but it does address finding the number of periods in the sample.

Comment: This is interesting and I'm looking into it. I'm trying to figure out what autocorrelation does and how it works, and whether this helps, and what the answer means. It's nice that you've changed a very wiggly function into a smooth one.

Comment: Autocorrelation is correlating the function with itself - good for finding repeating patterns when you don't know the period. It can be efficiently done with Fourier transforms as well.

Comment: perhaps you could help this user better than I did : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466255/how-to-calculate-correlation-between-time-periods

Comment: You can use `ListCorrelate` as well for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

```
(* the data *) 

data = Table[N[753+919*Sin[x/623-125]], {x,1,25000}]; 

(* Find the position of the largest Fourier coefficient, after 
removing the last half of the list (which is redundant) and the 
constant term; the [[1]] is necessary because Ordering returns a list *) 

f2 = Ordering[Abs[Take[Fourier[data], {2,Round[Length[data]/2+1]}]],-1][[1]] 

(* Result: 6 *) 

(* Directly find the least squares difference between all functions of 
the form a+b*Sin[c*n-d], with intelligent starting values *) 

sol = FindMinimum[Sum[((a+b*Sin[c*n-d]) - data[[n]])^2, {n,1,Length[data]}], 
{{a,Mean[data]},{b,(Max[data]-Min[data])/2},{c,2*f2*Pi/Length[data]},d}] 

(* Result (using //InputForm):  

FindMinimum::sszero:  
   The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by 
   the PrecisionGoal option, but the gradient is larger than the tolerance 
   specified by the AccuracyGoal option. There is a possibility that the method 
   has stalled at a point that is not a local minimum. 

{2.1375902350021628*^-19, {a -> 753., b -> -919., c -> 0.0016051364365971107,  
  d -> 2.477886509998064}} 

*) 


(* Create a table of values for the resulting function to compare to 'data' *) 

tab = Table[a+b*Sin[c*x-d], {x,1,Length[data]}] /. sol[[2]]; 

(* The maximal difference is effectively 0 *) 

Max[Abs[data-tab]] // InputForm 

(* Result: 7.73070496506989*^-12 *)
```

Although the above doesn't necessarily fully answer my question, I found it 
somewhat remarkable.

Earlier, I'd tried using `FindFit[]` with `Method -> NMinimize` (which is 
supposed to give a better global fit), but that didn't work well, 
possibly because you can't give `FindFit[]` intelligent starting values.

The error I get bugs me but appears to be irrelevant.