# How to calculate correlation between time periods

Tags: math, statistics

if I have 2 lists of time intervals :

List1 :
1. 2010-06-06 to 2010-12-12
2. 2010-05-04 to 2010-11-02
3. 2010-02-04 to 2010-10-08
4. 2010-04-01 to 2010-08-02
5. 2010-01-03 to 2010-02-02

and 
List2 :
1. 2010-06-08 to 2010-12-14
2. 2010-04-04 to 2010-10-10
3. 2010-02-02 to 2010-12-16

What would be the best way to calculate some sort of *correlation* or similarity factor between the two lists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try with [Cross-Correlation](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/miscellaneous/correlate/).

However, you should be aware that you have vector data (start, length), and the algorithms suppose a functional dependency between them. That depends on the semantic of your data, which is not clear from the question.

HTH!

[A more useful link for your current problem here.](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/asp/2007/089150.pdf)

Comment: hello belisarius!  [and the algorithms suppose a functional dependency between them] : Could I get more details on that please? [That depends on the semantic of your data] : Please, how could I clarify my question, what would be missing? Thank you :)

Comment: @ibiza Please read the second link first, then post another question if you have doubts on any algorithm.

Comment: @belisarius : ok, I will take plenty of time to carefully read this. It is almost like your answer is already accepted :p Thank you!

Comment: @ibiza The second paper is about medical apps ... but the concepts hold

Comment: @belisarius : after reading the first part and getting a quick glimpse of the rest, I can honestly say this will take me...weeks to digest :) I am glad you found this however it is definitely a notch above my current knowledge. I will try to dissect it and find the important parts regarding my problem.

Comment: @ibiza Wait. I'll try to get something easier.

Comment: @ibiza Sorry, I am unable to find a really easy intro for vector cross correlation :(. Scalar cross correlation is much easier, but that doesn't allow you to have two magnitudes (starting time and duration) for each point. Really sorry. Perhaps you may post this problem in MathExchange http://math.stackexchange.com/ and get better help

Comment: @belisarius I will try my luck at mathexchange and thanks sincerely for the article nonetheless :)

Answer (score 2):

Is that the extent of the data or just a sample to give an idea of the structure you have?

Just a few ideas about how to look at this... My apologies if it is redundant to your current state in looking at this set.

Two basic ideas come to mind for comparing interval like this: absolute or relative. A relative comparison would ignore absolute time for the interval data and look for repeating structures or signature that occur in both groups but not necessarily at the same time. The absolute version would consider simultaneous events to be relevant and and it doesn't matter if something happens every week if they are separated by a year... You can maybe make this distinction by knowing something about the origin of the data.

If it is the grand total of data available for your decision about associations it will come down to some assumptions about what constitutes "correlation". For instance, if you have a specific model for what is going on - e.g. a time to start, time to stop (failure) model you could evaluate the likelihood of observing one sequence given the other. However, without more example data it seems unlikely you'd be able to make any firm conclusions.

The first interval in the two groups are nearly identical so they will contribute strongly to any correlation measure I can think of for the two groups. If there is a random model for this set, I would expect that many models would show these two observations and "unlikely" just because of that.

One way to asses "similarity" would be to ask what portion of the time-axis is covered (possibly generalized to multiple coverage) and compare the two groups on that basis.

Another possibility is to assign a function that adds one for each sequence that occurs during any particular day in the overall interval of these events. That way you have a continuous function with a rudimentary description of multiple events covering the same date. Calculating a correlation between the two groups might give you suggestions of structural similarity, but again you would need more groups of data to make any conclusions.

Ok that was a little rambling. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hi and thanks for joining in! The data shown here was fictive and the real data comes from automated strategies : any trade can have an interval from a few minutes to many days and there are many strategies trading altogether (each strategy is then represented by a list of trades). Some strategies will only open trades between say 2pm and 5pm (but trades are not guaranteed to occur) while some others work 24/24 and try to find opportunities to open trades at any time. I am not sure which one of the relative or absolute way of comparing the intervals would be the best for my case...